# Unable to Load Audio Files with Unicode Characters in File Name in just_audio_windows

Tags: flutter, audio, desktop-application, just-audio

**Description:**
When attempting to load audio files with Unicode characters in their names, such as `дуу.mp3`, the [just_audio_windows](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_windows) package seems to encounter issues.

```dart
// not actual production code but example
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

void loadUnicodeAudio() {
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  audioPlayer.setFilePath('D:/examplefolder/дуу.mp3');
  // Add code for audio playback.
}

void loadUnicodeAudio2() {
  final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  audioPlayer.setFilePath('D:/дуу/song.mp3');
  // Add code for audio playback.
}
```

**log:**

> [just_audio_windows] Item error: The system cannot find the path specified.

Instead, the audio player throws an exception or fails to load the file properly when Unicode characters are present in the file name.

**Environment:**

- just_audio : ^0.9.31
- just_audio_windows: ^0.2.0

Flutter version: 3.10.2
Operating System: Windows 11

The [just_audio_windows](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio_windows) and [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) packages should load and play audio files with Unicode characters in their names without any errors.

Comment: You might try submitting a bug report to just_audio_windows on GitHub

Comment: No errors with regular file names?

Comment: yes okey with file path contains only ascii table character but not with unicode.

Comment: @RyanHeise some one already did it. https://github.com/bdlukaa/just_audio_windows/issues/23

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to replace:
flutter pub add dart_vlc

Comment: Yea, If there is no further development in this repo I am intend to replace it.